# Trying to find a proper way to have global access to a canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, global-variables

I'm still kinda new to Javascript and noticed in lot of places in my code I am using JQuery to get a reference to my canvas element like this:

`$('#myCanvas')[0].getContext('2d');`

I have my suspicions that it is slowing my site down because I have it in a lot of places that may be called quite often. Ideally, I'd just do this once and access the context from any javascript page.

I tried to make a global variable but it didn't see to work (probably because it runs before the page can load) so instead I put this function in global scope in my first referenced javascript file:

```
var drawingCanvasContext;

function getDrawingCanvas() {
    if (drawingCanvasContext == null) {
        drawingCanvasContext = $('#myCanvas')[0].getContext('2d');
    }

    return drawingCanvasContext;
}
```

So then whenever I need the canvas in my code I just call that method.. But it just seems rather.. messy. I doubt this is an uncommon desire so I'm curious of the proper solution. I'd prefer it just to be a variable instead of a function and to be accessed globally without all these null checks. Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: There's no way that's slowing your site down.  Accessing elements by id is really fast. If you're trying to do it thousands of times a second, well, maybe, but I'd figure out a way not to do it thousands of times a second before I worried about that directly.

Comment: No, this is just how it is done.

Comment: Well, I have to access my canvas during drawing code so it could be running that often. Right now I'm just passing the canvas context to the drawing code to prevent accessing it from slowing down the site but I'm really just sick of having this same line of code repeated in a hundred different places and would rather just have global access to a variable that references it.

Comment: Can't you just set `drawingCanvasContext` to the context in a `$(document).ready` and use that variable? I don't fully see the use of the function here.

Comment: If something's slow, its *far* more likely to be the drawing process itself, or computations involved with the drawing. You might want to try the profiler tools in Firebug or Chrome to investigate.

Comment: @pimvdb: Oh yeah I guess that would work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this

```
var drawingCanvasContext = $('#myCanvas')[0].getContext('2d');
```

instead of defining a function for that.

If you're careful about global scope pollution, you should wrap it up in a function or use namespacing. E.g.

```
var myNamespace = myNamespace || {};
myNamespace.drawingCanvasContext = $('#myCanvas')[0].getContext('2d');
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got only two little improvements on your code:

```
(function(){
    // move the var out of the global context by wrapping everything in a closure
    var /* static */ drawingCanvasContext;

    function getDrawingCanvas() {
        if (!drawingCanvasContext) // no need to check for null, defaultvalue is undefined
            drawingCanvasContext = $('#myCanvas')[0].getContext('2d');
        return drawingCanvasContext;
    }

    window.getDrawingCanvas = getDrawingCanvas;
})();
```

Of course you could/should put that method in a namespace object, I guess you have more than one of such.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately all you can do is store the context around to be retrieved afterwards. The problem I can see here is probably an order of operations, the context is being requested before the page is ready, and possibly you're losing scope with your VAR declaration (i think).

```
;(function($, window, document) {

   /* private */ var canvas = null;
   /* private */ var context = null;

   $(document).ready(function() {
      canvas = $("#myCanvas")[0];
      context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      $('body').trigger('CanvasReady', [canvas, context]); // You can fire an event to bind to with jquery for when the canvas is ready.
   });

   /* public */ window.getCanvas = function() { return canvas; };
   /* public */ window.getCanvasContext = function() { return context; };

   // You can also use a namespace here too if you want
   // window.Canvas = {};
   // window.Canvas.GetContext = ... etc ...

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

This will aquire the canvas when it's ready, fire an event you can subscribe to for when the canvas has been found and is ready for manipulation.

It will expose 2 functions globally:

`getCanvas` which will get you the Canvas Instance
`getCanvasContext` which will get you the Canvas Context

You can adapt this to use a registry pattern if you want so it can aquire & store multiple canvas elements/contexts but this is just a simple pattern to show you.

*Note: It returns null if the methods are called before the canvas/document is ready, you should be doing all of your setup code after domReady anyway.*

Comment: I'm sorry but isn't the whole closure thing here a bit overkill? The two functions are just as "polluting" as the two variables would be.

Comment: It isolates the actual instance variables, and only exposes the public accessors. This is more a force of habit than a guideline, he's welcome to use the global space if he wants. I also use closures because it helps with minification later, so yes it may be a little out of scope for the question but i dont see the harm.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a getter on your global variable that will execute each time you read from that variable (see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/09/07/transitioning-existing-code-to-the-es5-getter-setter-apis.aspx) for tips on making this backward compatible):

```
var _drawingCanvasContext;//behind the scenes variable that keeps the value
Object.defineProperty(this, "drawingCanvasContext", {
    get: function() {
        return _drawingCanvasContext || (_drawingCanvasContext = $('#myCanvas')[0].getContext('2d'));
    }
});
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/N6H7p/) where I set it to 'foo' to show you how it works.